# Future.timeout works only once

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a future builder that wraps a future received as an argument.

My goal is to have some standard behaviour on timeout, which allows the user to retry.

Using Future.timeout this seems simple, however, after the first timeout all subsequent retries throw TimeoutExceptions instantly. Is there a hidden way of resetting the timer?

```
  Future<void> _asyncLogic() async {
    try {
      await widget.onConfirm().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    } on TimeoutException {
      print('timed out');
      setState(() {
        _future = null;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      setState(() {
        _future = null;
      });
    }
  }

  void _handleConfirm() => setState(() {
        _future = _asyncLogic();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your logic, you don't need a Timer though.

Create a `retries` variable and a `maxRetries` const or final.

```dart
  int retries = 0;
  final maxRetries = 3;
```

Each time you get a `TimeoutException` you can increase the `retries` and check if you passed the `maxRetries`, otherwise, call the `_asyncLogic` again.
Also, you don't need a setState in `_asyncLogic` because you are already using it in `_handleConfirm`.

```dart
  Future<void> _asyncLogic() async {
    try {
      _future = await widget.onConfirm().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    } on TimeoutException {
      retries++;
      if (retries < maxRetries) {
        _asyncLogic();
      } else {
         if(mounted){ 
            navigatorKey.currentState!.pop(true);
         }
      }
      print('timed out');
        _future = null;
      
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      
        _future = null;
     
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want an auto retry, I want the option to retry on button press. e.g. it failed due to network failure, and the user can retry once they have regained signal. Also my bad that timer is not related, I use the timer so the loading spinner is not jarring for the user, will remove from my question

Comment: add this to your FutureBuilder: 

FutureBuilder(key: UniqueKey(),

Comment: tried that too, no luck unfortunately

Comment: If you use the code I posted, what's the result? here we assign the future:  _future = await widget.onConfirm().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2)); , and if you are using a FutureBuilder it should trigger the action

Comment: I have no need to try your code because I don't need an auto retry, thank you for your help though

Comment: if you don't need autoretry  , just remove , if (retries < maxRetries) { and else condition, and add a unique to your FutureBuilder, that should works

Comment: so the problem stems from the Dio http client. I am using a global cancelToken, and on timeout exception I'm calling `cancelToken.cancel();` when I remove this line it all works as expected. I guess I have to refactor to use Dio's built in timeout